# How can I modify files on a remote computer over wifi/3g from my Android phone/tablet?

Tags: applications, file-management

I have a scenario where I watch a fair amount of video content from a DLNA device that doesn't support deleting (GoogleTV, via Logitech Revue). I would like to be able to delete files after I'm done watching them, without using my laptop to RDS/FTP/etc to the file server.

In a perfect world I would be able to do it from the DLNA player (which I realize would be a question for another StackExchange site, but I've done a fair amount of research on this and I'm pretty sure it's just not possible yet...), but I would accept an Android-friendly solution -- since I have an Android phone -- that I could use to connect to the file server and delete the files as an acceptable alternative.

Before getting the Revue I accomplished this using my XBox360 as a Windows Media Center Extender, which in addition to allowing me to watch my content, was capable of deleting.

The file server is running Windows 7. I want a point & click, turnkey solution, so I'm not interested in an SSH-like or RDP-like solution, because I don't want to type out directory navigation commands or do lots of pinch-to-zoom + drag + click on my phone. I could more quickly and easily just walk into the other room and delete the files. Some sort of native file browser would be best, I think.

Comment: I think this is more of a Windows question than an Android question.  Either way, app recommendations are offtopic, and it's better to ask "How can I do X?" because quite often there are non-app solutions.

Comment: It may be pretty windows-centric, but I'd say it's also very Android-centric. Trying to ask the same question on a windows-specific stack exchange site would probably result in comments like "go to android.stackexchange.com" -- since I'm interested in an Android solution but not an iOS solution, for instance. I see your point about app recommendations, but perhaps this rides the fringe of on-topic? I will rephrase to not specifically request an app, but will stick to my intention of looking for a turnkey solution over building something myself.

Comment: I see your point.  Rephrasing the question should be fine :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found [ES File Explorer](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.estrongs.android.pop) which seems to do what I need, and a little bit more. This looks pretty promising. I'll report back if I have any issues with it, but for now it seems to answer my question.

Comment: Does ES File Explorer allow you to make changes over 3g/4g?

Comment: If you can connect and have permissions, it should. It supports FTP, SSH, and all kinds of other connections; even Google Drive and Dropbox.

Answer (score 0):

You can log into a Windows box using Remote Desktop, and use the Windows interface to delete files like you normally would.  The RDP app I use is called [Remote RDP](https://market.android.com/details?id=org.toremote.serversmanager).

You could also do something like install IIS and create yourself a simple webpage that would list the files and allow you to click a button to delete them.

Comment: I have used RDP but it is not as quick or friendly as I would like. It's a shoehorn. I've thought about writing a quick webapp that will let me do it right from my TV with the Revue keyboard, but I'm not sure I want to go through the effort.

Answer (score 0):

On my tablet I use [File Manager HD](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.rhmsoft.fm.hd).

I have shortcuts saved in its left-hand bar that take me straight to the right folders in the shares of my server with username and password saved. One click on the shortcut takes me straight to the relevant content folder, and then it's a long press on a file or folder to rename, delete or move, which are the three things I normally want to do with media files after watching them.